Having trouble with the python env with vscode
It's stuck in a "reactivating environment" cycle, and I'm stuck on how to fix it... Below is the output it gives. Any ideas?
2024-10-28 06:07:47.079 [error] sendStartupTelemetry() failed. [l [Error]: Failed to resolve env "C:\\Users\\alask\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python3.12.exe"
    at ae (c:\Users\alask\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2024.16.1-win32-x64\out\client\extension.js:2:2051686)
    at oe (c:\Users\alask\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2024.16.1-win32-x64\out\client\extension.js:2:2049646)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (c:\Users\alask\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2024.16.1-win32-x64\out\client\extension.js:2:2045940)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:483:21)] {
  code: -4,
  data: undefined

The sendStartupTelemetry() is tickling something in the back of my mind, but I don't think that's it.
I've tried everything on this detailed list from a search...

Check the Python Locator error: In the search results, one user reported an error related to the Python Locator. If you encounter a similar error, try reinstalling the Python extension or updating VSCode to the latest version.
Verify virtual environment settings: The issue might be related to the automatic activation of virtual environments in VSCode terminals. Check your settings.json file for the setting "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true. If you want to disable this behavior, set it to false.
Inspect terminal settings: Review your terminal settings in VSCode. Ensure that the terminal is configured to use the correct interpreter and that the virtual environment is properly set up.
Check for conflicts with other extensions: Other extensions might be interfering with the terminal’s behavior. Try disabling all extensions except the essential ones and see if the issue persists.
Clear VSCode cache and storage: Sometimes, clearing the VSCode cache and storage can resolve issues. You can do this by deleting the .vscode folder and restarting VSCode.
Reinstall VSCode and extensions: If none of the above steps work, try reinstalling VSCode and its extensions.
Check for OS-specific issues: The issue might be related to your operating system. If you’re on macOS, try disabling GPU acceleration for the terminal, as mentioned in one of the search results.
Monitor terminal logs: Keep an eye on the terminal logs to identify any errors or patterns that might indicate the cause of the issue.
Try a different terminal emulator: If the issue persists, try using a different terminal emulator, such as the built-in terminal or a third-party extension like Terminal-Here.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This seems similar like a bug which should fixed in v14.1.You could try the following steps and see if it can be resolved:
1.Change "python.locator"in settings.You may see either native or js .Please switch between each other and see which one works for you.You can also do this by changing usersettings json file.
2.Roll back your extension to v14.1 which should fix the issue.
